# Schedule notification to fire every day at X h:Y s and redirect to specific View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm in trouble with creating an app that fires it's notification every day at the same time.
In my case this time should be 9:00 Ante Meridiem (AM)

I'd like to fire this notification when the application is not present in the foreground, so it was killed before or just simply moved to background.

I can redirect the user to my page with this method from AppDelegate:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

    var storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var dvc:UINavigationController = (storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("xyzID") as? UINavigationController)!

    self.window!.rootViewController = dvc
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a local notification, your app delegate's [`application(..., didReceiveLocalNotification ...)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ro#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW4) method is called.

In response to that call, you could write code to navigate to the desired view controller. I don't know what your "Reveal view controller" is, but I assume it's something like [this](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), which has methods for revealing the hidden VC.

Comment: Okay, now I am able to redirect the user to view controller, but scheduling is still present. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Did you create the local notification? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

Comment: Of course I did, it's popping up when I switch to background mode, but there is some kind of problem with schedule, because the push notification appears immediately after switching to background even with fire date set to different date, this is the base of my problem

Comment: Sounds like you might have called `presentLocalNotification:` instead of `scheduleLocalNotification:`

Comment: I'm using `scheduleLocalNotification:` method, link to source code:
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wxPqY3ES)